# vertical synchronous scrolling in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I found a sample where horizontal synchronous scrolling works. [Here is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4307/) 
Can someone help me out on how to do vertical scrolling ?
I tried following in the same sample

```
e.target.scrollTop = scrollTop;
```

but the scrolling does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

You had not set `overflow-y: auto;` for top and bottom div as well no width was set.
The updated link is this:http://jsfiddle.net/gdjz6go5/

Comment: The code works on jsfiddle but when I copy it to my IDE and use it, I am not able to get the scroll event.

Comment: yes I tried, the scroll event is not fired when I scroll.